# Cannot use yii\base\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name yii2 advance

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I just bougth a stronger pc, installed composer and wanted to continue my project on it but when I use gii it give me this error.
How can I fix it ? Why am I getting it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

solved. since 2.0.13, the class name `Object` is invalid since PHP 7.2, use [[BaseObject]] instead. So in the vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/CodeFile.php just had to change Object to BaseObject.

Comment: change all `Object` to `BaseObject` in that file save me.. cz yii has both file, idk if else context.. i see them in other link..

Answer (score 1):

solved. since 2.0.13, the class name Object is invalid in PHP 7.2,

//Replace
//class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface

class User extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface

And Download the yii-basic-app-2.0.25 from https://www.yiiframework.com/download
after that copy the yiisoft folder from vendor and replace the yiisoft folder in your project in vendor folder

Now check your project will be working fine.
Its work for me hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i change file 
/vendor/trntv/yii2-command-bus/src/middlewares/BackgroundCommandMiddleware.php
use yii\base\Object; to use yii\base\BaseObject;
and 
class BackgroundCommandMiddleware extends Object implements Middleware
to ;
class BackgroundCommandMiddleware extends BaseObject implements Middleware