# Cannot use Conekta\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name

Tags: laravel, postman

I'm trying make a oxxo references pay with Conekta, this is with PostMan because is a web services, when I try consume the ws I get the next wrong:

```
FatalErrorException in Resource.php line 5:  
Cannot use Conekta\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name  
1. in Resource.php line 5
```

I read that this problem is caused por the version but I have the latest version of Conekta "4.0.4", this is to PHP 7+, my PHP version is 7.3.

So, someone can help me please?
I have 2 days with this problem, and on Internet I have not found anything.

This is my code

```
private function payWithOxxoPay($payment_token) {

      $amount = (int) $this->package->price * 100;

      // Processing payment
      $this->payment_type = 'Conekta_Oxxo';
      $this->payment_status = 'Procesando';
      $this->payment_reference = "promo_" . $this->id;
      $this->save();

        Conekta::setApiKey(config('app.conekta_private_key'));
        $chargeData = [
            "amount"=> $amount,
            "currency"=> "MXN",
            "description"=> "Promoción " . $this->package->title,
            "reference_id"=> $this->payment_reference,
            "card"=> $this->payment_token,
            'details' => [
                'name'=> $this->user->name . ' ' . $this->user->last_name,
                'phone'=> $this->user->phone ?: '38109948',
                'email'=> $this->user->email ?: 'default@turnmyapp.com',
                'line_items'=> [
                    [
                        'name'=> "Promoción " . $this->package->title,
                        'description'=> "Promoción " . $this->package->title,
                        'unit_price'=> $amount,
                        'quantity'=> 1,
                        'sku'=> 'promo_pack_' . $this->package->id,
                        'category'=> 'Promotion'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
       $charge = \Conekta\Charge::create($chargeData);
}
```

Comment: The error mentions `Resource.php line 5`. Add the related code of that file.

Comment: is a line code of Conekta API. This is teh line `use \Conekta\Object;`

Comment: The code that you pasted is a method that uses the `Object` class nowhere.. it just references `Konecta` once.. could you please add the full classes related to see why the error is generated? By the way try this: `use \Conekta\Object as ConektaObject;` and use the class as `$c = new ConektaObject();`

Comment: But I never call to `\Conekta\Object;`, in my classes only `use Conekta\Conekta;`

Comment: What about that `Resource.php` class?

Comment: that class is located in `vendor/conekta/conekta-php/lib/Conekta/Resource.php` is part of the API

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7.2, `Object` cannot be a class name any more. It seems the library you are using (Conekta) is not ready for it yet.

Replacing the class name by something else will help overcome this issue.

See [Cannot use yii\base\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name yii2 advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50269306/cannot-use-yii-base-object-as-object-because-object-is-a-special-class-name-yi) for another library with the same problem that causes 7.2-incompatibility.